# How to share data between two threads

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

I am creating an application using Tkinter. I have two Threads, the first is an algorithm that looks for results and the second is my Tkinter window that displays the number of results found.

```py
import time
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread

global results
results = []

class thread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        global results
        if self.name == "algo":
            algo()
        elif self.name == "window":
            window = Tk()
            tmp = StringVar()
            tmp.set(str(len(results)))
            text = Label(window, textvariable=tmp, font=(None, 12))
            text.place(x=10, y=15)
            window.mainloop()

def algo():
    global results
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        results += [1]
        print(len(results))

thread_1 = thread("algo")
thread_2 = thread("window")
thread_1.start()
thread_2.start()
thread_1.join()
thread_2.join()
```

The problem is that the textvariable does not update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the `tkinter` `mainloop` in the mainthread, and your function in a specially spawned new `Thread`. It does not appear necessary to have more:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread

def algo():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        result.set(result.get() + 1)
        print(result.get())

root = tk.Tk()
result = tk.IntVar(value=0)
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=result)
label.pack()

thread_1 = Thread(target=algo)
thread_1.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `global results` (do you mean `global result` actually?) is not necessary.  Setting initial value of `IntVar` should be `IntVar(value=0)` as `IntVar(0)` means `IntVar(master=0)`.

Comment: Entirely correct @acw1668, thank you, good catch. I edited out these remnants of the Op's code.